# Counting number of string that are in another array without repetition

Tags: arrays, c, function

I'm trying to program the mastermind game and I'm stuck in the loop to check colors on the wrong place but right colors.

What I have right now duplicates the real number. For example if I have a right color in right place, but that color is also elsewhere it counts as many times as it appears, even if I dont have that color on my guess, in another place.

The outcome should be
3 Right colors in right place!
1 Right colors in wrong place!

and not
3 Right colors in right place!
2 Right colors in wrong place! because red is only one in random generated colors (The code is just for testing because it will be generated randomly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>
#define QTD  5   // Number of colors
#define MAX 10   // Number of characters in string
#define DIM  5   // Number of colors in vector colors

int identical(char aux[10],char secretCode[5][10]){

int j,i;
for (j = 0; j < QTD; ++j)
{
    if(strcmp(aux, secretCode[j]) == 0){                              
        return 1;
    }
}
return 0;
}

void compareGuess(char secretCode[5][10],char guessCode[5][10], 
int *black, int *white){

int i, j,found=0;
//contadores
*black = *white = 0;
char aux[10],pontos[5][10];

for(i=0; i<QTD; i++){   
    //Se a cor for igual e na mesma posicao incrementa o numero 
 black
    if(strcmp(tentativaCode[i], secretCodigoCores[i]) == 0){                                
        ++*black;
    }            
} 
for(i=0; i<QTD; i++)
{
    strcpy(aux,tentativaCode[i]);
    if(identical(aux,secretCodigoCores)==1)
    {
        strcpy(aux,pontos[i]);
        found++;
    }
}
*white=found-*black;
if (*white<=0)
{
    *white=0;
}
printf("\n %d colors in right place!",*black); 
printf("\n %d colors in wrong place!!",*white);                  
}
```

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre]. That is, include the code that sets things up and calls this function in a way that reproduces the problem. Then give the exact expected vs actual result.

Comment: You need two loops, one for the black pegs, and a separate loop for the white pegs. In both loops, you need to keep track of which `tentativaCode` strings were matched, so that you don't use the same string twice.

Comment: The outcome should be 3 black, and 0 white. Red, blue and brown are the correct color in the correct place. The other two reds don't match.

Comment: Exactly, and I cant figure out how to do it.

Comment: There's a big difference between something being ubiquitously famous and something being famous in your opinion.  I personally don't know the game's rules, even though I remember seeing it in the games cupboard back in the 1980s some time.  If your question relies on knowledge of the rules, you should state them.

Comment: Its not paddy, I do now the rules...its about mark how many colors are in the guess code that are equal to the ones in the secret code of colors, but not in the same place.

Comment: This would probably be easier explained if you had an `enum` instead of an `array 5 of array 10 of char`.

Comment: I see that [several versions exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)). It would help if you outlined the game as it is in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks Neil, Iǘe figure it out. The answer is on top.